# How to call ember actions synchronously

Tags: ember.js

I want execute couple of ember actions synchronously, what is the right way to do this. For example

```
this.send('closeModal');
this.send('openModal','login'); // run when `closeModal` is totally executed
```

or how to call action in route without using `send`

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
actions:{
   openModal: function () {
    //how to execute like this.closeModal(); without .send
       ... logic...
    });
   closeModal: function () {
       ... logic...
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could move the action logic to other functions on the route i.e.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  openModal: function() {
    ...logic...
  },

  closeModal: function() {
    ...logic...
  },

  actions:{
    openModal: function () {
      this.closeModal(); // Ensure other modals are closed.
      this.openModal();
    });

    closeModal: function () {
      this.closeModal();
    });
  }
});
```